# Pausing and resuming tic tac toe win animation

Tags: java, android, multithreading, animation, pause

I have made tic tac toe and have added an animation in the end... Every time the firecracker animation plays bottom to up it is overlapped by the button (attached screenshot). I want to know if there is a simple way to use threading over here to stop the process before making the buttons visible so that the firecracker animation can easily finish.

Here's the code:

```
for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions)
            {
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] && gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] && gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {
                    // Someone has won!
                    gameActive = false;

                    String winner = "";

                    if (activePlayer == 0) {
                        winner = "O";
                    } else {
                        winner = "X";
                    }

                    Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);
                    TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);
                    winnerTextView.setText(winner + " has won!");

                    ImageView firecracker = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.firecracker);
                    firecracker.setTranslationY(-1000);
                    firecracker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    firecracker.animate().translationYBy(-3000).setDuration(1000);
                    firecracker.setTranslationY(4000);
                    playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
```

Onclick method for the play again button:

```
public void reset(View view)
    {
        ImageView firecracker = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.firecracker);
        firecracker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);
        TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);
        playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Full code:

```
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // 0: X, 1: O, 2: Empty

    int [] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
    int [][] winningPositions = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {0,3,6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}};
    boolean gameActive = true;



    int activePlayer = 0;


    public void dropIn(View view)
    {
        ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;


        int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

        if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameActive)
        {

            gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;


            counter.setTranslationY(-2000);
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);

            counter.animate().translationYBy(2000).setDuration(300);

            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.o);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }


            boolean emptySquare = false;
            for (int squareState : gameState) {
                if (squareState == 2) {
                    emptySquare = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!emptySquare && gameActive) {
                // Game is a draw
                gameActive = true;
                Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);
                TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);
                winnerTextView.setText("Game is a draw...");
                playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


            for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions)
            {
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] && gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] && gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {
                    // Someone has won!
                    gameActive = false;

                    String winner = "";

                    if (activePlayer == 0) {
                        winner = "O";
                    } else {
                        winner = "X";
                    }
                    Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);
                    TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);
                    winnerTextView.setText(winner + " has won!");

                    ImageView firecracker = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.firecracker);
                    firecracker.setTranslationY(-1000);
                    firecracker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    firecracker.animate().translationYBy(-3000).setDuration(1000);
                    firecracker.setTranslationY(4000);

                    playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void reset(View view)
    {
        ImageView firecracker = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.firecracker);
        firecracker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);
        TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);
        playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winnerTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout gridLayout = (android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            ImageView counter = (ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
            counter.setImageDrawable(null);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++)
        {
            gameState[i] = 2;
        }

        activePlayer = 0;

        gameActive = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I read the question right theres one method I usually use and that's to create a sleep method.. The code goes as follows:

```
static void Sleep(int ms)
{
  try {
    Thread.sleep(ms);
   }catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

If I read the question right that is, and my interpretation is that you want to pause the thread for a short period of time and then resume it.

In order to implement this, just call Sleep({Time in milliseconds}) before you make the buttons visible

Comment: When I add this, before the buttons go visible and after the firecracker animation, for some reason my last marker takes that much time before dropping and then displays the animation and turns the button visible together... I have added my code... Please tell me where to add it.. I think it might be due to my for loop

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/synchronized-in-java/
Sorry for the breif response. This website might help you out and Ill get back to you later

Comment: Okay Im back again but only for a brief period of time. I can give you a tad bit of insight here opposed to just a link for help. Synchronized methods are your best bet in this situation, if you're familiar with c# its exactly the same as an async method with slight differences if any other than naming. This can allow you to run multiple threads at once and be able to run the button showing script as soon as the rocket stops its animation. I misread the original question,  the reason why it paused was that my sleep method pauses the whole program. If you need help implementing this I can help

Comment: Yes, if you could help implementing that it would be appreciated... I am unable to understand the example given on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/synchronized-in-java/